# UITapGestureRecognizer not working for specific [UIView] array

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the following piece of code. It's a third party library for a menu (named CarbonKit). When I try to select a specific segment (tab) and add a gesture recognizer, it doesn't work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

To be clear, I placed a breakpoint in the handleTap, it it doesn't even enter the function.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let tgr : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(OverviewFolder.handleTap(_:)))
        // segment 2 (categories)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.segments![2].userInteractionEnabled = true
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.segments![2].addGestureRecognizer(tgr)
}

 // tap
    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let test = carbonTabSwipeNavigation.currentTabIndex
        if test == 2 {
            print("second item tapped")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if `carbonSegmentedControl` is not nil when you add gesture? Also are you using Swift 2 or Swift 3?

Comment: @alexburtnik I'm using Swift 2.3, and the carbonSegmentedControl is not nill, it gives back Optional(<CarbonTabSwipeSegmentedControl: 0x102116720; baseClass = UISegmentedControl; frame = (0 0; 768 29); opaque = NO; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 0; layer = <CALayer: 0x1702277e0>>)

Comment: Several thoughts. First, what is carbonTabSwipeNavigation? Next, assuming carbonSegmentedControl is your UISegmentedControl, why are you trying to add a tap gesture to a specific button? It already **has** a tap built-in. Couldn't you simply code against UISegmentedControl.valueChanged() and check the selectedSegmentIndex?

Comment: @dfd is there any way i can use the build in tap? the segmentedcontrol is indeed a UISegmentedControl

Comment: Did you add gesturerecogniserdelegate ?

Comment: @Jecky yes I have

Answer (score 0):

If the 3rd party UISegmentedControl is like the generic one, you already have everything you need. Here's some of my code. If you are using IB, wire the control up to an IBAction instead.

```
let imageSegments = UISegmentedControl (items: ["Original","Stained"])

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageSegments.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
    imageSegments.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
    imageSegments.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeImageView), for: .valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(imageSegments)
}

func changeImageView() {
    switch imageSegments.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        imageView.image = imgOriginal
    case 1:
        imageView.image = imgEdited
    default:
        break
    }
    imageView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I press my already pressed segment again (that's the moment I actually need it to send me a change). Any way on how I can do that?

Comment: The cause is due to how a segmented control **should** operate. I now see your issue. My guess - just that, a guess - is that you are running into a conflict. That is, the "out-of-box" functionality of a UISegmentedControl is higher up on the responder chain than the tap recognizer (in your original question) and the tap (1) is "squelched" or "cancelled" in the receiver - the UISegmentedControl - because you are **already** using that segment, and thus (2) that tap never makes it beyond there in the chain. About the only thing you can do is rethink things, reengineering your UI or subclassing.